# Can we access JavaScript object on Serverside C# asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0, client-side, serverside-javascript

Here in my Asp.net web application I have to generat `pdf`,  earlier I used to achive this task using **itextsharp** *(server side / paid services)* , now  i found **jspdf** can be done on client side plus point it is *open source.*

Heres sample code which generate pdf

```
  var doc = new jsPDF();
  doc.text(20, 20, 'Hello world!');
  doc.text(20, 30, 'This is client-side Javascript, pumping out a PDF.');
  doc.addPage();
  doc.text(20, 20, 'Do you like that?');
  doc.save('Test.pdf');
```

For real work I need to get data by applying some logic (server side coding) ,  so i want to know whether i can access **doc**  on serverside  i.e ( c# ) or any another way to do ?

Comment: @Juhana: thank you, but none of the answer was right marked, and it also tagged as `asp.net mvc`, where mine is simple asp.net c#

Comment: The principle is exactly the same regardless of what the server-side technology is. That none of the answers are accepted doesn't mean that they wouldn't be correct.

Answer (score 2):

You can't access the `doc` object (the jsPDF object). What you can do is that the client asks the server the data it needs through a webservice or some rest api, OR if what you need is pdf signing, the client could send the pdf to the server in some way (through a webservice or some rest api) and then the server could send back the pdf... But this would make it useless to use a client-side pdf generation.

There are some other options: if you make the button that generates the PDF make a roundtrip to the server (and then after the roundtrip it launch the generation of the PDF), then some additional data can be inserted in the page by the server, so

```
<asp:Button ID="btnPdf" runat="server" Text="Generate PDF" OnClick="btnPdf_Click" />

and in btnPdf_Click:

ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "PdfKey", "GeneratePdf();", true);

and in the Javascript:

function GeneratePdf()
{
    // If it's a string, it's better that you escape the content of <%= %>
    // for example with HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode in ASP.NET 4.0
    var serverData = <%= SomeNetVariableFilledByBtnPdf_Click %>;
    // generate the pdf
}
```

Comment: thanks for your prompt reply, what am understanding now i have to call ajax request and get data in response and attachd to my `doc` variable. As its a open source i am trying to do some rnd over it

Comment: @Satindersingh Yes, but you don't pass the `doc` variable around.

Comment: thanks your edited answer gave me a good idea